# Azure: How to diagnose role startup on compute emulator?

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis

I have a web role running as [cloud service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-choose-me). It fails to start on the [Compute Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-emulator-express-debug-run). I'm deploying the application without Visual Studio. I'm using cspack and csrun (see [here](http://www.bardev.com/2013/03/12/how-to-deploy-application-to-windows-azure-compute-emulator-with-csrun/) and [here](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/building-running-and-packaging-windows-azure-applications-from-the-command-line)).

The emulator UI shows this:

```
[fabric] Role Instance: deployment27(17).MyService.MyWebRole.0
[fabric] Role state Suspended
[fabric] Role state Aborted
[fabric] Role state Suspended
[fabric] Role state Aborted
... (repeats forever)
```

The Event Viewer shows no error on (Windows Logs > Application), (Windows Logs > System) or (Applications and Services Logs > Windows Azure). I have some Information events like this:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
  <Provider Name="Windows Azure Runtime 2.7.0.0" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">20001</EventID> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>1</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-01-05T00:34:37.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>18996</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Windows Azure</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-HK8J9A33</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
  <EventData /> 
</Event>
```

The [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx) tool shows this:

```
[8016] [00008016:00006468, INFO ] Initializing runtime. 
[8016] Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
[8016] Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
[8016] Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
[8016] Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
[8016] Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
[8016] [00008016:00006468, INFO ] Health monitor thread started. Thread Id = 8264. 
[8016] [00008016:00008264, INFO ] Waiting for 500 ms before next role status check. 
[8016] [00008016:00006468, INFO ] Successfully initialized runtime. 
[9000] [00009000:00000744, INFO ] Initializing runtime. 
[9000] Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
[9000] Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
[9000] Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
[9000] Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
[9000] Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
[9000] [00009000:00000744, INFO ] Health monitor thread started. Thread Id = 8416. 
[9000] [00009000:00008416, INFO ] Waiting for 500 ms before next role status check. 
[9000] [00009000:00000744, INFO ] Successfully initialized runtime.
... (repeats forever)
```

I don't have Visual Studio to debug.

Is there anything I can do to know what is crashing?

Comment: `It fails to start on the Compute Emulator` Are you trying to run on local machine? If so, why don't you debug in Visual Studio?

Comment: You can see some logs under C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\dftmp. BTW I also have a role startup problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926079/role-in-azure-compute-emulator-stuck-cycling-between-unknown-and-destroyed-state) and DebugView shows a lot of "Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function." for me too.